# Get rid of print output from Sklearn pipeline.predict()

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I have an Sklearn pipeline that I am using to make thousands of predictions and I find it annoying that it prints an output on each iteration. My model outside of the pipeline prints nothing. Here is an example when making one prediction

```
pipeline.predict(X_val)
2136/2136 [==============================] - 0s 20us/step
```

Verbose defaults to False when I initially make the pipeline, but that seems to only affect the fitting portion.

Whether there is a setting I can turn off or some hacky way around the problem, I'm all ears.